# What is the type of a 2D array of pointers, and how can it be stored?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

If I have a table of int pointers, ie
`int *arr[3][3]`

Is it possible to store this in a pointer, while still retaining the array information?

While regular assignment (int ***p = arr) throws an incompatible pointer error, it is possible to cast `int ***p = (int***)arr`. However, accesses to the information via `*arr[1][2]` will not return the correct data

Comment: *However, accesses to the information via `*arr[1][2]` will not return the correct data*  That's because an `int ***` has nothing to do with referring to a "2D array of pointers" despite what you may have been told.  The closest an `int ***` can come is a pointer to a 1D array of multiple, separate 1D arrays of pointers to `int *`.  And that's not a 2D array.  Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.  Arrays in some cases [decay to a pointer to their first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).

Answer (score 2):

When `arr`, having been declared as `int *arr[3][3]` is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. The type of that pointer is `int *(*)[3]`.

So `int *(*p)[3];` will declare a pointer of that type, after which you can assign `p = arr` and use `p` to access array elements as if it were `arr`.

Comment: `int *(*p)[3];` does not meet "while still retaining the array information", yet makes most array accessing easier to code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: OP just wants `*p[i][j]` to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `int *arr[3][3];` and you'd like a pointer to that, then I suggest:

```c
int *(*parr)[3][3] = &arr;
```

Dereferencing it will bring the full type back with all the support you'd expect from the compiler:

```c
(*parr)[2][2] = something;
```